# select a subkey in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, key

I'm working with a dictionary with multiple keys, like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'Mouses': {'White': {'Small': 1, 'Big': 2}, 'Black': {'Small': 3, 'Big': 4} },
        'Cats':   {'White': {'Small': 5, 'Big': 6}, 'Black': {'Small': 7, 'Big': 8} }, 
        'Dogs':   {'White': {'Small': 9, 'Big': 1}, 'Black': {'Small': 2, 'Big': 3} } }
```

If I want to get the number of `'Big'-'White'-'Cats'`, it's simple. But what if I want all the `'White'-'Cats'`? Or All the `'Dogs'`? Is there a way to easily access all values within a given subkey? A sort of query of subkeys with a sum over all values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: most probably not the answer you are looking for. I am learning list comprehention at the moment. made one for you **just for fun**. i suggest not to use this kind of comprehension in your code. it will be confusing to read. `total_cats = sum([sum(a.values()) for a in [x for x in list(dict['Cats'].values())]])`

Comment: @Nesi - note only `total_cats = sum(sum(a.values()) for a in dict['Cats'].values())` is needed. Also @urgeo **dict** has a specific usage for a Class in Python and this should not be over-ridden by using it as your variable name.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a recursive function that drills down the dictionary using or aggregating results as it goes down the hierarchy (`all` is used as wildcard to indicate aggregation):

```
def zooCount(z,key=all,*subKeys):
    if not isinstance(z,dict): return z
    if key is all:
       return sum( zooCount(v,*subKeys) for v in z.values()) 
    return zooCount(z.get(key,0),*subKeys)

zoo = {'Mice':   {'White': {'Small': 1, 'Big': 2}, 
                  'Black': {'Small': 3, 'Big': 4} },
       'Cats':   {'White': {'Small': 5, 'Big': 6}, 
                  'Black': {'Small': 7, 'Big': 8} }, 
       'Dogs':   {'White': {'Small': 9, 'Big': 1}, 
                  'Black': {'Small': 2, 'Big': 3} } }

print(zooCount(zoo, "Cats","White", "Small")) # 5
print(zooCount(zoo, all,   "White", "Small")) # 15 
print(zooCount(zoo, all,   "Black", all))     # 27
print(zooCount(zoo, "Dogs","Blue",  all))     # 0

# you can omit trailing wildcards:

print(zooCount(zoo, "Cats", "White"))    # 11
print(zooCount(zoo, "Dogs"))             # 15        
print(zooCount(zoo))                     # 51
```

If you're not comfortable with recursion, an iterative approach can be used, by progressively going down the hierarchical levels building a list of dictionary with matching keys until the list reaches the deepest level and contains the filtered numbers to add up:

```
def zooCount(z,species=all,color=all,size=all):
    result = [z]                      # list of dictionaries
    for key in (species,color,size):  # filter next level
        result = [v for d in result for k,v in d.items() if key in (k,all)]
    return sum(result) # final list is numbers to add up
```

Comment: Love this. Really elegant and simple solution